# How to take a snapshot of webpage from the url?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, canvas, html2canvas

I want to take a snapshot of the webpage from the url. The url is an html web page which is dynamic. Basically  we needed an img of that webpage.

I thought to convert the html page to image in c# but din't work.
I first read the html using streamreader and using NReco.ImageGenerator tried to convert into bytes and finally image. This isnt working.
Finally I am trying to convert html to canvas using javascript from inside the html web page.

```
function report() {
let region = document.querySelector("body");
 html2canvas(
 $('body'),
 {allowTaint: true, logging: true,'onrendered': function (canvas) 
 {}}).then( //getting problem here at then
 function (canvas) {
 let jpgUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  console.log(jpgUrl);
  var text = "bottom-right Brochure1";
 var imageName = text + '.jpg';
 download(jpgUrl,imageName, "image/png");
 }
```

Code explained - It will take a snpashot of the body element in the html page using js. Take the url and create the canvas from the url. and automatically download. But i face a issue ------- " html2canvas(...),then is not a function"  .. I dont know why its happening. Please help.

Comment: Thank you .. But this isn't working for me. I want the snapshot to be taken from inside the html url only.

Comment: Sorry, since you mentioned C#, I assumed you were trying to do this server-side

Comment: no problem. its js

Comment: Well, html2canvas is a third party library, so did you add it to the page first before using it?

Comment: Yup I have added it. Here it is  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>  Let me know if its correct.

Comment: Did you check your network tab to see if it loads correctly?

Comment: Yes it loads correctly. @ADyson

Comment: Try passing it `document.body` instead of `$('body')`. Their documentation doesn't mention jQuery at all

Comment: On a sidenote, there's also third-party web services which convert a URL to an image, [like this one](https://www.url2png.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Because of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) restrictions in all modern browsers, this can't be done purely on the clientside. You need something on the server-side to accomplish this. To do it in javascript on the server use NodeJS there are several npm packages that can help like: node-server-screenshot, PhantomJS etc